# How to check the backtrace of a "USER process" in the Linux Kernel Crash Dump

Tags: linux, coredump

I was trying to debug a USER Process in Linux Crash Dump.

The normal steps to go to the crash dump are:

1. Go to the path where the dump is located.
2. Use the command `crash kernel_link dump.201104181135`.

Where `kernel_link` is a soft link I have created for vmlinux image.

Now you will be in the CRASH prompt.
If you run the command `foreach <PID Of the process> bt`
Eg:

```
crash> **foreach 6920 bt**

**PID: 6920   TASK: ffff88013caaa800  CPU: 1   COMMAND: **"**climmon**"****

 #0 [ffff88012d2cd9c8] **schedule** at ffffffff8130b76a
 #1 [ffff88012d2cdab0] **schedule_timeout** at ffffffff8130bbe7
 #2 [ffff88012d2cdb50] **schedule_timeout_uninterruptible** at ffffffff8130bc2a
 #3 [ffff88012d2cdb60] **__alloc_pages_nodemask** at ffffffff810b9e45
 #4 [ffff88012d2cdc60] **alloc_pages_curren**t at ffffffff810e1c8c
 #5 [ffff88012d2cdc90] **__page_cache_alloc** at ffffffff810b395a
 #6 [ffff88012d2cdcb0] **__do_page_cache_readahead** at ffffffff810bb592
 #7 [ffff88012d2cdd30] **ra_submit** at ffffffff810bb6ba
 #8 [ffff88012d2cdd40] **filemap_fault** at ffffffff810b3e4e
 #9 [ffff88012d2cdda0] **__do_fault** at ffffffff810caa5f
 #10 [ffff88012d2cde50] **handle_mm_fault** at ffffffff810cce69
 #11 [ffff88012d2cdf00] **do_page_fault** at ffffffff8130f560
 #12 [ffff88012d2cdf50] **page_fault** at ffffffff8130d3f5

    RIP: 00007fd02b7e9071  RSP: 0000000040e86ea0  RFLAGS: 00010202
    RAX: 0000000000000000  RBX: 0000000000000000  RCX: 00007fd02b7e9071
    RDX: 0000000000000000  RSI: 0000000000000000  RDI: 0000000040e86ec0
    RBP: 0000000040e87140   R8: 0000000000000800   R9: 0000000000000000
    R10: 0000000000000000  R11: 0000000000000202  R12: 00007fff16ec43d0
    R13: 00007fd02bcadf00  R14: 0000000040e87950  R15: 0000000000001000
    ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffffff  CS: 0033  SS: 002b
```

If you check the above backtrace it shows the kernel functions used for scheduling/handling page fault but not the functions that were executed in the USER process (here eg. `climmon`).
So I am not able to debug this process as I am not able to see the functions executed in that process. 
Can any one help me with this case?

Answer (score 1):

You can not debug a userspace process from a kernel crash dump. If your kernel crashed it was most certainly the fault of the kernel and not some userspace process. The kernel should always behave properly no matter what userspace process runs on it. If you want to debug a userspace process I recommend looking at ltrace, strace and gdb.

Gergely from toptal.com

Comment: Maybe your first phrase is correct, but all the remaining part is not sensible at all. I am just dealing with a system hang where the only thing i was able to do (was I?), was to trigger the kernel crash dump using Magic SysReq. Machine was responding to pings but ssh was stuck. It will be useful to see what was happening in the userspace as well (it displays process list) so in theory it could have userspace stacks as well. But i do understand the privacy concerns that might have driven the authors of kernel dump mechanisms.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is what you want. But you can try a crash extension call "gcore". It can dump a user process core from kernel crash file.

Also, make sure you include user page when you are dumping.

Answer (score 1):

Load the dump with gdb:
  gdb vmlinux

Load these gdb macros: http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kdump/gdbmacros.txt

(gdb) source gdbmacros.txt

Use 'btt' to "dump all thread stack traces on a kernel compiled with CONFIG_FRAME_POINTER":

(gdb) btt

Use 'bttnobp' to "dump all thread stack traces on a kernel compiled with !CONFIG_FRAME_POINTER":

(gdb) bttnobp